# unicode flat file can't find CRLF row delimiter

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a csv file that contains unicode characters (specifically Hindi characters) that I need to import using SSIS.  When I set the connection to unicode, SSIS cannot find the CRLF delimiters.  If I uncheck the unicode check box, it finds the CRLF delimiters just fine.

How can I correctly import this data?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than ticking the "Unicode" checkbox beside the "Locale" drop-down, leave the checkbox blank and pick "65001 (UTF-8)" option from the "Locale" drop-down instead. I discovered it just today after wasting some 30 minutes trying various combinations of encodings etc. May work in your case as well.